# "latexmk" command not found in emacs

Tags: latex, environment, path

I updated my texlive to 2022 recently and found that the auto-compilation command in tex-mode running `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=xelatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -file-line-error  file.tex` throws this error:

```
/bin/sh: latexmk: command not found
TeX Output exited abnormally with code 127 at Mon May  9 15:51:01
```

My attempted solutions:

1. I am pretty sure the new path of texlive2022 was added to my `$PATH`, I also tried `echo $PATH` in the built-in shell of Emacs, it also gives the correct path names.
2. I've tried the answer in [Trying to run a linux program in Emacs: command not found](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20773/trying-to-run-a-linux-program-in-emacs-command-not-found), i.e., add the path to `~/.profile`, but it doesn't work as well.
3. I also checked out using `M-x getenv path`, and it does contain the path inside emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the third attempted solution works.

Put a line in `config.el`

```
(setenv "PATH" "...")
```

actually works.

Comment: Did you set `PATH` to something different from the environment value? If yes, what did you change?

Comment: I set it to be precisely the environment value outside (its original value is different from that).